# Why does Arduino IDE give me a compiling error when I include the SoftTimer library?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino-ide

I have started dipping my toes into the waters of the Arduino. I have set my mind on a project where I use a piezo buzzer to play a few songs based on the input of a button. I have the songs written as functions, and I couldn't figure out how to stop them with a button once they started, so I eventually came to the conclusion that I should use multithreading(protothreading?). I was using the Tone.h library to make the buzzer make noise, and SoftTimer.h library to run the function that detects a button press and stop the sounds, and the functions of the songs themselves. I had received an error when I added the line `#include <SoftTimer.h>`, and the error was:

```
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer0_pin_port'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer0_pin_mask'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer1_pin_port'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer1_pin_mask'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer2_pin_port'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer2_pin_mask'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer0_toggle_count'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer1_toggle_count'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `timer2_toggle_count'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_7'
libraries/ToneLibrary/Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno
```

I have no idea what this means, or how to solve this. I am fairly young, and very inexperienced in C++, so please don't get mad at me if I don't know something simple.

Comment: The linker is reporting that two functions with the same name exists in two different objects and it doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: Please add which lib you are using to the question.

Comment: Looks like adding `#include <SoftTimer.h>` exposed pre-existing errors. Basically you went from being stopped by compiler errors to being stopped by linker errors. It's not `#include <SoftTimer.h>`'s fault. My educated guess is `timer0_pin_port` and friends are defined in a header and shouldn't be. Two translation units include the header (or one file with a broken header) and the jig is up.

Comment: What are you referring to by saying "which lib"?

Comment: Does this contain any information you can use? https://github.com/bhagman/Tone/issues/11 ? I've been reading through the results from a google search on `timer0_pin_port`. You should do the same because you're a lot closer to the ground and better able to make experiments to narrow down exactly what the problem is and fix it. When you do, consider self- answering.